# How to afix shower rail to tiles?

Tags: bathroom

I have an expandable (by twisting) shower rail, that was secured with some kind of glue or silicone putty between the tiles in my shower.

I brought this down by hanging a soaked towel on it. The ends seem to be rubber.

How can I firmly and perhaps more securely re-affix this to my tiles?

Comment: Do you mean a shower _rod_ (designed to hold a shower curtain)?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to have any additional adhesive on the rod or wall for it to stay up properly. You can try to clean the wall and rod thoroughly to see if that helps. You can also try to tighten it (making it longer). If you find that you have to tighten it to the point where the rod itself it starting to bow, or it is pushing out the wall, then it it way too tight. If you have to excessively tighten it, then that would indicate that the rod has worn out and should be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if it is perfectly horizontal, and that the walls are, in, fact straight, and not flexing.

Apart from that, the rubber feet tend to wear out.  Likewise, because these are held in place by compression, putting a heavy wet towel on them tends to make them flex and bow, and then fall out-- they are notorious for this.

I replaced mine with a screwed in shower bars.  I also added a laundry cord over the center of the tub; total cost was around $50.